# Windows 8.1 Waiting Lock Pool Tag FLwl - High Memory Usage

Tags: drivers, windows-explorer, windows-8.1, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am running Windows 8.1 with 8gb of ram and have lately been experiencing crashing issues with windows explorer when RAM utilization is over ~73%.

I have run poolmon.exe to see if there are any memory leaks.

[image: Poolmon Results]

My specific question is in regards to the first item listed with tag 'FLwl'.
Google searches have shown that this tag is associated to 'Waiting lock'.
Is this a normal windows process? Is the large difference between allocation and frees something to be concerned about?

Although I am using this in a development environment at work, thus I have several instances of Visual Studio, web pages, etc. open... it seems that given what is in use shown by the windows resource monitor there should be more free RAM than I have.

Comment: how long does it take to have this large amount of used RAM with this tag? If it is a short period, use xperf to capture some of the usgae: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-48-WPT-Memory-Analysis-Pool and uplaod the zipped ETL file.

Comment: have you generated the ETL file which captures a grow?

Comment: seems like you don't want help any longer.

Comment: I have been monitoring the problem for a number of days and it seems that it takes about half a day of use for the RAM to be filled, can this still be tracked given that it is a long period? Also, the poolmon tags for the processes that are using the RAM vary.

Comment: try to capture some of the grow, not all.

Comment: Ok, Monday morning when I come to work I will reboot and try to catch the grow as the day goes on.

Comment: have you ever uploaded the trace? Or is the issue now fixed?